# Show that the function $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, given by $g(x)=x^2f(x)$, is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Could anyone guide me step by step how to solve this problem or give me some pointers. I recently came across it and I can't seem to solve it.

Here's the entire problem:

Suppose that the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at all real numbers $x,x\neq 0$, and satisfies the condition $\displaystyle \left\vert f(x)\right\vert \leq \frac{1}{\left\vert x\right\vert}$ for all $-1\leq x\leq 1$. Show that the function $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, given by $g(x)=x^2f(x)$, is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you.

Comment: it would be helpful for us to guide you if you can explain till what part you have tried (successfully/ unsuccessfully)....

Comment: We have $|g(x)|=|x|^2|f(x)|\leqslant |x|^2|x|^{-1}\leqslant\cdots$?

Comment: You will have to define $g(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

for $x > 1$ and $x<-1$, the function $h(x) = x^2$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$,and since $f(x)$ is also continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ except at $x=0$ then the product $g(x) = h(x)f(x)$ is also continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for $|x|>1$. For $|x| \le 1$ you can use the hint from Pedro Tamaroff above.

Comment: You meant to say that $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and that the hint helps to show continuity in $0$.